# The foreign key is not storing the actual value for related models

Tags: php, mysql, yii, relational-database

I am doing a small application in Yii.For that I have the database like this

```
=============
 +   GROUP    +
 =============
 + id(pk)     +
 + name       +
 + description+
 ++++++++++++++


  =============
 +   MEMBERS  +
 ==============
 + id(pk)      +
 + group_id(fk)+
 + name        +
 + description +
 ++++++++++++++
```

Relation in `Group model` is like this

```
public function relations()
  {
    return array(
      'members' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'Members','group_id'),
    );
  }
```

and Relation in `Members model` is like this

```
 public function relations()
  {
    return array(
      'group' => array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Group','group_id'),
    );
  }
```

as per requirement I have `rendered Members in Group model`.So my `controller for action create` is like this

```
    public function actionCreate()
  {
    $model=new Group;
    $members=new Members;
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
     $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Group'],$_POST['Members']))
    {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Group'];
      $members->attributes=$_POST['Members'];
      $valid = $model->validate();
      $valid = $members->validate();
      if($valid)
      {
        $members->save(false);
        $group->save(false);
        $members->group_id = $model->getPrimaryKey();

        $model->save(false);
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
      }
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'members'=>$members,
    ));
  }
```

So by this the `primarykey of Group model should be same as the forignkey of group_id in the members model`.But it is not showing like that.The `group_id is remaining '0'` every time.Can someone tell me what is the wrong part here?

Comment: I don't believe `getPrimaryKey()` will return anything before the model is saved, you'll only be able to use that after `$model->save()`, also you're setting the `$members->group_id` after you `$members->save()`, also it looks like `$group->save(false);` should be `$model->save(false);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$model->getPrimaryKey()` you are calling:

- Firstly, could be used as `$model->primaryKey`
- Secondly is returning the primary key of a new record, which hasn't been inserted yet, so it doesn't have one.

Save the parent record first before adding any children `$group->save(false);` is trying to do that but `$group` isn't a model :)